# Construct identification between $L^2( \Omega;H)$ and $L^2(T \times \Omega)$ where $H=L^2(T, \mathcal B,\mu)$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, malliavin-calculus

I am reading page 31 of Nualart, 
 ["The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics"](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=DRxGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=L2(%CE%A9;+H)+can+be+identi%EF%AC%81ed+with+L2(T+%C3%97%CE%A9)&source=bl&ots=_KwoHJlbUn&sig=ACfU3U0s-4PlZgzdt-PdJAk-sRhMNoKYAw&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijsuekwbrgAhVHVbwKHcL8CNQQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=L2(%CE%A9%3B%20H)%20can%20be%20identi%EF%AC%81ed%20with%20L2(T%20%C3%97%CE%A9)&f=false) .

Here, it says that there is an identification between the Hilberts spaces $L^2( \Omega;H) $ and $L^2( T \times\Omega) $ where $H=L^2(T, \mathcal B,\mu)$ and $\mu$ is atomless.

How can I contruct this "natural identification"? I know that $L^2(T \times \Omega) \cong L^2(T) \bigotimes L^2(\Omega)$, but I don't see how this helps.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is just $f \in L^{2}(\Omega, H) \to g$ where $g(t,\omega)=f(\omega) (t)$. The fact that this is an isometry follows immdiately from Fubini's Theorem.